# PHP - Verify user token on every request

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here is a scenario: Whenever a user logs in, I send the user token along with the response and save it in localStorage. Now, I want to make another request and I also want to send the token back for confirmation as a valid token.

Here is a sample MySQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM news WHERE status = '1'
```

Currently, I am not checking the token. How will I do that?

**Note:** The token is in the user table.

Comment: why localStorage and not sessions?

Comment: it would be easier to store it sessions, otherwise you have to add headers or place as an additional parameter in GET which will make this far more complicated that it should be. There are bette options than using localStorage

Comment: This is a solved problem in most [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/). Typically they use something like a secret + hash to verify the token, as stored in the session, or some other method like encryption. Writing your own version of same can be very time-consuming, painful, and easy to mess up. Check out something like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/)
 which will give you this support out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer, its [SQL EXIST OPERATOR](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp) , Can i get my upvotes now? Thanks